# Avoiding Unique error E11000 with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have been using [this mongoose plugin](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate) to perform `findOrCreate` which is used very often in the codebase.

I recently realized that performing multiple asynchronous `findOrCreate` operations when the unique index is created easily leads to an `E11000` duplicate key error.

An example can be described by the following using `Promise.all`. Suppose `name` is unique then:

```
const promises = await Promise.all([
  Pokemon.findOrCreate({ name: 'Pikachu' }),
  Pokemon.findOrCreate({ name: 'Pikachu' }),
  Pokemon.findOrCreate({ name: 'Pikachu' })
]);
```

The above will certainly fail since `findOrCreate` is not atomic. It makes sense after thinking about it why it fails but, what I would like is a streamlined way of approaching this problem.

Many of my models use `findOrCreate` and they are all subject to this problem. One solution that comes to mind would be to create a plugin that would catch the error and then return the result of `find` however, there may be a better approach here - possibly a native mongoose one that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly depends on your intended usage of this, but I would say overall that "plugins" are just not required. The basic functionality you are looking for is already "built in" to MongoDB with ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option).

By definition, an "upsert" cannot produce a "duplicate key error" as long as the query condition to "select" the document is issued using the "unique key" for the collection. In this case `"name"`.

In a nutshell you can mimic the same behavior as above by simply doing:

```
let results = await Promise.all([
  Pokemon.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": "Pikachu" },{},{ "upsert": true, "new": true }),
  Pokemon.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": "Pikachu" },{},{ "upsert": true, "new": true }),
  Pokemon.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": "Pikachu" },{},{ "upsert": true, "new": true })
]);
```

Which would simply "create" the item on the first call where it did not already exist, or "return" the existing item. This is how "upserts" work.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a022f48edca148094f30e8c",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a022f48edca148094f30e8c",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a022f48edca148094f30e8c",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

If you really did not care about "returning" each call and simply wanted to "update or create", then it's actually far more efficient to simply send **one** request with [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite):

```
// Issue a "batch" in Bulk
let result = await Pokemon.bulkWrite(
  Array(3).fill(1).map( (e,i) => ({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "name": "Pikachu" },
      "update": {
        "$set": { "skill": i }
      },
      "upsert": true
    }
  }))
);
```

So instead of awaiting the server to resolve three async calls, you only make **one** which either "creates" the item or "updates" with anything you use in the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) modifier when found. These are applied on every match including the first, and if you want "only on create" there is [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) to do that.

Of course this is just a "write", so it really depends on whether it is important to you to return the modified document or not. So "bulk" operations simply "write" and they do not return, but instead return information on the "batch" indicating what was "upserted" and what was "modified" as in:

```
{
  "ok": 1,
  "writeErrors": [],
  "writeConcernErrors": [],
  "insertedIds": [],
  "nInserted": 0,
  "nUpserted": 1,           // <-- created 1 time
  "nMatched": 2,            // <-- matched and modified the two other times
  "nModified": 2,
  "nRemoved": 0,
  "upserted": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "_id": "5a02328eedca148094f30f33"  // <-- this is the _id created in upsert
    }
  ],
  "lastOp": {
    "ts": "6485801998833680390",
    "t": 23
  }
}
```

So if you do want a "return", then a more typical case is to separate which data you want on "create" and which is needed on "update". Noting that the [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) is essentially "implied" for whatever values are in the "query" condition to select the document:

```
// Issue 3 pokemon as separate calls
let sequence = await Promise.all(
  Array(3).fill(1).map( (e,i) =>
    Pokemon.findOneAndUpdate(
      { name: "Pikachu" },
      { "$set": { "skill": i } },
      { "upsert": true, "new": true }
    )
  )
);
```

Which would show the modifications applied in "sequence" of each atomic transaction:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a02328fedca148094f30f38",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a02328fedca148094f30f39",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a02328fedca148094f30f38",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": 2
  }
]
```

So generally it's "upserts" that you want here, and depending on your intent you either use separate calls to return each modification/creation or you issue your "writes" in a batch.

As a complete listing to demonstrate all the above:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const pokemonSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  skill: Number
},{ autoIndex: false });

pokemonSchema.index({ name: 1 },{ unique: true, background: false });

const Pokemon = mongoose.model('Pokemon', pokemonSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    // Await index creation, otherwise we error
    await Pokemon.ensureIndexes();

    // Clean data for test
    await Pokemon.remove();

    // Issue 3 pokemon as separate calls
    let pokemon = await Promise.all(
      Array(3).fill(1).map( e =>
        Pokemon.findOneAndUpdate({ name: "Pikachu" },{},{ "upsert": true, "new": true })
      )
    );

    log(pokemon);

    // Clean data again
    await Pokemon.remove();


    // Issue a "batch" in Bulk
    let result = await Pokemon.bulkWrite(
      Array(3).fill(1).map( (e,i) => ({
        "updateOne": {
          "filter": { "name": "Pikachu" },
          "update": {
            "$set": { "skill": i }
          },
          "upsert": true
        }
      }))
    );

    log(result);

    let allPokemon = await Pokemon.find();
    log(allPokemon);

    // Clean data again
    await Pokemon.remove();

    // Issue 3 pokemon as separate calls
    let sequence = await Promise.all(
      Array(3).fill(1).map( (e,i) =>
        Pokemon.findOneAndUpdate(
          { name: "Pikachu" },
          { "$set": { "skill": i } },
          { "upsert": true, "new": true }
        )
      )
    );

    log(sequence);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})()
```

Which would produce the output ( for those too lazy to run themselves ):

```
Mongoose: pokemons.ensureIndex({ name: 1 }, { unique: true, background: false })
Mongoose: pokemons.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: pokemons.findAndModify({ name: 'Pikachu' }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { upsert: true, new: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
Mongoose: pokemons.findAndModify({ name: 'Pikachu' }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { upsert: true, new: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
Mongoose: pokemons.findAndModify({ name: 'Pikachu' }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { upsert: true, new: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f82",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f82",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f82",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
Mongoose: pokemons.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: pokemons.bulkWrite([ { updateOne: { filter: { name: 'Pikachu' }, update: { '$set': { skill: 0 } }, upsert: true } }, { updateOne: { filter: { name: 'Pikachu' }, update: { '$set': { skill: 1 } }, upsert: true } }, { updateOne: { filter: { name: 'Pikachu' }, update: { '$set': { skill: 2 } }, upsert: true } } ], {})
{
  "ok": 1,
  "writeErrors": [],
  "writeConcernErrors": [],
  "insertedIds": [],
  "nInserted": 0,
  "nUpserted": 1,
  "nMatched": 2,
  "nModified": 2,
  "nRemoved": 0,
  "upserted": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f87"
    }
  ],
  "lastOp": {
    "ts": "6485804004583407623",
    "t": 23
  }
}
Mongoose: pokemons.find({}, { fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f87",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "skill": 2
  }
]
Mongoose: pokemons.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: pokemons.findAndModify({ name: 'Pikachu' }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$set': { skill: 0 } }, { upsert: true, new: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
Mongoose: pokemons.findAndModify({ name: 'Pikachu' }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$set': { skill: 1 } }, { upsert: true, new: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
Mongoose: pokemons.findAndModify({ name: 'Pikachu' }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$set': { skill: 2 } }, { upsert: true, new: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f8b",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f8b",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a023461edca148094f30f8b",
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": 2
  }
]
```

> **N.B** The [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) is also "implied" in all "mongoose" operations for the purpose of applying the `__v` key. So unless you turn this off, that statement is always "merged" with whatever is issued and thus allows the `{}` in the first example "update" block which would be an error in the core driver due to no update modifier being applied, yet mongoose adds this one for you.
>
> Also note that [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) does not actually reference the "schema" for the model and bypasses it. This is why there is no `__v` in those issued updates, and it does indeed bypass all validation as well. This is usually not an issue, but it is something you should be aware of.

Comment: Hey Neil, thank you so much for the very detailed answer you provided. Really thanks for taking the time! I have learned so much from your examples. I did encounter an interesting issue however. Your first async `findOneAndUpdate` example works perfectly but when I add `unique: true` to the field `name` then mongoose throws an E11000 error. To be more specific, I added the index in my test suite using `mongoose.connection.collections['pokemons'].createIndex({ 'name': 1 }, { 'unique': true }, function(){});`. I am wondering if you can shed some light on this. Thank you!

Comment: @dipole_moment You really need to read it again and learn some more. There is a "unique index" created in the listing provided, but I don't create the index like you think you do. There is another way to create the index that actually ensures there is not a "race condition" on the creation process to the first writes. Look carefully and see that I am deliberately "awaiting" the index creation before doing anything else. Code works fine with a unique index, it's a "timing" issue.